# Combining three arrays into one

Tags: java, merge

Here's my program, but it won't run and I don't know how to fix it...It throws an exception!

It's supposed to combine the three arrays and sort the new array of length 12 and print that out. I would appreciate it if you didn't fix it right away, since this is homework. But I know everything, I just can't seem to be able to figure this out! I'm bad with exceptions...Here's the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
    at Combine.Combine(Combine.java:25)
    at Combine.main(Combine.java:12)
```

here's the program:

```
public class Combine {

        public static void main(String[] args){

            int[] a = {1,4,5,6 };
            int[] b = {3,8,9,11};
            int[] c = {0,2,7,10};

            Combine( a, b, c);

        }

        public static int[] Combine(int[] a, int[] b, int[] c)
        {


            int[] answer = new int[12];
            int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, p = 0;

            while (i < 5 && j < 5)
            {
                if (a[i] < b[j])       
                    answer[k++] = a[i++];

                else        
                    answer[k++] = b[j++];               
            }

            while (i < 5 && p < 5 )
            {
                if (a[i] < c[p])
                    answer[k++]= a[i++];
                else
                    answer[k++]= c[p];
            }

            while (j < 5 && p < 5 )
            {
                if (b[j] < c[p])
                    answer[k++]= b[j++];
                else
                    answer[k++]= c[p++];
            }


            while (i < 5)  
                answer[k++] = a[i++];

            while (j < 5)    
                answer[k++] = b[j++];

            while (p < 5)    
                answer[k++] = c[p++];

            return answer;
        }

        }
```

Comment: If it were me I'd just populate the `answer` array and then sort it. `Arrays.sort()`.

Comment: It's ok to be bad at exceptions, every one is at first, but you should learn how to handle them. This is very easy to debug. Print some info, check your index variables/loops, and if necessary, step through your code using a debugger. The first step is of course to understand the errors. Most of them have descriptive names, like this one.

Comment: I seriously recommend that you learn to use a debugger.  It's one of the most important tools in a good programmer's toolbox.  You would have found your error right away if you had used a debugger here.

Comment: it is pretty easy, except whatever I do it's either an error or just doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use 4 basically everywhere where you use 5.

In Java an array **arr** of 4 elements has **arr.length=4**,
and normally you loop through it like this

```
for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
    // do something
}
```

So try changing 5 to 4.
By using 5 you're going out of bounds of the array.

Even better, use this kind of loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    // do something
}
```

The latter is a much better practice,
than hard-coding the length of 4. The 
same remark applies to while loops.

Comment: I would have used arr.length but why do that when I have the exact number?

Comment: @user3132078 Because in a week or a month your teacher or boss may ask you to make your program run correctly for 6 or 60 numbers and not just for 4. Think what you'll need to change then if you used your approach (with 4 hard-coded), and if you used the other approach (with arr.length).

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
while (i < 5 && j < 5) //and while (i < 5 && p < 5 ) and while (j < 5 && p < 5 )
```

and this

```
while (i < 5) // and j and p.
```

to -->

```
while (i < 4 && j < 4) //and while (i < 4 && p < 4 ) and while (j < 4 && p < 4 )
```

and

```
while (i < 4) // and j and p.
```

The indexing goes from 0 to 3, not 1 to 4, that's why you're getting that exception.

Comment: Yep, length is 4, which means you access the elements 0, 1, 2 and 3 :-)

Answer (score 1):

all your arrays have a length of four, meaning valid indices from 0 to 3. However in that code you access index 4:

```
    while (i < 5 && j < 5)
    {
        if (a[i] < b[j])       
            answer[k++] = a[i++];
        else        
            answer[k++] = b[j++];               
    }
```

It happens because your while condition checks that the index is below 5. It would be safer to check below a.length and b.length.

Meanwhile, it would even be safer to rely on existing methods of the API:

- System.arraycopy()/Arrays.sort()
- List.addAll()/Arrays.asList()/List.toArray()

Answer (score 0):

use `<4` instead of using `<5`

or you can use like this

```
for (int val: arr)
{
  //do something            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you array is having 4 elements, so its having length 0-3 and in if-condition you are checking it for 0-4.Hence its giving error.
If you replace it by 4 instead of 5 the code will run fine.

public class Combine {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] a = { 1, 4, 5, 6 };
    int[] b = { 3, 8, 9, 11 };
    int[] c = { 0, 2, 7, 10 };

    Combine(a, b, c);

}

public static int[] Combine(int[] a, int[] b, int[] c) {

    int[] answer = new int[12];
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, p = 0;

    while (i < 4 && j < 4) {
        System.out.println("@"+i);
        if (a[i] < b[j])
            answer[k++] = a[i++];

        else
            answer[k++] = b[j++];
    }

    while (i < 4 && p < 4) {
        if (a[i] < c[p])
            answer[k++] = a[i++];
        else
            answer[k++] = c[p];
    }

    while (j < 4 && p < 4) {
        if (b[j] < c[p])
            answer[k++] = b[j++];
        else
            answer[k++] = c[p++];
    }

    while (i < 4)
        answer[k++] = a[i++];

    while (j < 4)
        answer[k++] = b[j++];

    while (p < 4)
        answer[k++] = c[p++];

    return answer;
}
```

}

Comment: The code is running fine,
I have got the output as 
 1  3  4  5  6  0  2  7  8  9  10  11 
where its getting stuck in your case?
please check the braces

Comment: I'm getting 1
4
4
5
6

Comment: also- yours isn't sorted either...but I can sort it out myself that's not the problem...

Comment: The output i got after running the code for given test case is :-  1  3  4  5  6  0  2  7  8  9  10  11
which is sorted Array for that case.
Replace "5" by "4" in conditions of your code as length is 4 and index of array starts from 0. Inorder to remove the runtime error. I  didn't go into logic of code